# Locking sharable memory

Tags: windows, memory-management

Is there away to page into memory another process’s entire image?  In a couple of weeks, our IT staff will be replacing all of the "core" network switches.  This will bring down the network.  This will be done after normal business hours.  During this time, several users will still be using a program that I have written.  It will be a nightmare to install local copies of my program on each user's machine.  The program normally runs from a network share.  The only time the program will access the network is when the program executes its executable (image) code.  How can I get the Windows Memory Manager to load the entire image into memory and hold it "lock" there until the network is back online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can relink your program with the /swaprun:net option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0628bwh.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work.

Windows doesn't necessarily load a 'static' copy of the executable into memory, it's free to shuffle chunks around and page parts in and out. Often it loads resources (images, strings, etc.) from the executable after the program has started running. It often loads external libraries dynamically as well.

**Edited to add:**

*There is no such thing* as "a process's entire image". Every thread, for example, gets its own allocation.

Maybe you should explain why running from a different location (i.e., a local copy of the binary) won't work for you.

Comment: I'm aware of this.  I want to lock the image into memory.  There is a VirtualLock function to do this.  But it only efforts the calling process and I also need to figure out the base addresses and length of each section of the image.

Comment: Copying the program to the local disk would work if it didn't require access to some files on start-up which are on the server.  I'm sorry I didn't mention that.  I was hoping to write a small program that would call some system APIs to "lock" the code and data sections of the EXE into memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it so that it copies itself locally to temp directory and then have it run that copy as a separate process, and then kill itself(the first copy).  I've done this little juggling act before, but it depends on how your program works whether or not it will like being run from the temp directory.

Comment: This might work, but he seems to be saying that his program has to be "installed".

Comment: @egrunin Yeh, that's what I wondered. If they can just run it from the network without installing it, what difference would it make if it were just straight up copied to a different location.  Which is why I said it depends on how it works.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but my program requires a few files at start-up that should be present in the same directory as the program. I have another idea. I think if I compress my EXE with an EXE compressor like UPX, then the decompressed image would be consider private and therefore would be "backed" by the pagefile and not by the image on the server. What do you think?